# Handling a nullable relationship in a nested resolver in graphql

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I am building a graphql api with Express and express-graphql. I have eaUsers that may belong to a trainingLocation, but they may not.

```html
type EaUser {
        id: ID!
        email: String!
        firstName: String!
        lastName: String!
      ...
          trainingLocation: TrainingLocation
}
```

I've built a nested resolver to get the training location when querying on the eaUser:

```html
EaUser: {
        trainingLocation: async parent => {
            if (Object.keys(parent.relationships.trainingLocation).length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            const id = parent.relationships.trainingLocation.data.id;   
            return await getTrainingLocation(id);   
        }
    },
```

Then trying to do the query this way:

```html
{
    eaUsers {
        id
        email
        firstName
        lastName
        trainingLocation {
            id
            jatc
            name
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine for users that have a training location, but for those that don't, I'm getting an error that it "cannot read property id of null." I'm new to GraphQL, but I think that should be a valid query and just show "null" when the user doesn't have a training location. If that's the case, I clearly need to do something different with the resolver, but I'm not sure what. My search results have all been people who are getting null unexpectedly, rather than my situation, where I expect a null sometimes, but am getting an error instead. (The users with a training location are getting that resolved correctly.)

Comment: check/log parent.relationships.trainingLocation before ....data.id access?

Comment: Ah, that was it - there was a data property which was null in the ones I needed. Thanks!